# Write protobuf for map< string, repeated map <string, string > >

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": [
            {
                "code": "red",
                "text": "random sentence"
            },
            {"code": "blue"}
        ],
        "recent": []
    }
}
```

For above json, I want to have proper protobuf syntax. Below is just an outline to show the idea. I know that below proto won't work.

```
  syntax = 'proto3';

  map< string, repeated map <string, string > > response = 1;
```

How can I write this in protobuf syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot; the thing on the right in a `map` cannot be `repeated`; you'd instead have a `map<string, Foo>` for some `Foo` that *has`a`repeated` something.

Honestly, I think the key problem here is this statement:

> For above json, I want to have proper protobuf syntax.

Protobuf is not a general purpose JSON tool; the JSON it chooses is *strongly opinionated*. If you want to map pre-existing JSON, then protobuf *is not the right tool for you*; instead, use *any general purpose JSON tool* - they'll usually be fine with it. Instead, think of protobuf as a serialization tool that *happens to have* a JSON variant output (in addition to the primary binary output), but which offers very little flexibiltiy re JSON layout.

Comment: message Extra {
        map<string, string> infos = 1;
    }

    message ExtraList {
        repeated Extra extra_list = 1;
    }

    map<string, ExtraList> response = 16;


I was able to make my proto this way but I just want a list of dicts without naming each variable. Like in the json representation,  "extra_list" and "infos" need to be added. Do you know any other alternative to do this?

Comment: @DivyanshuShekhar no, basically